# the function xyz2uvl.m in matlab. It's implementation seems to strange

Tags: matlab

Wikipedia shows the conversion equations from XYZ to Luv as follows
[image]
However, the implementation of that in matlab is different. I don't know how does it make sense. Is there anything I miss?

The code below is the implementation of xyz2uvl in matlab.

```
black = 1.0e-16 .* [0.167115861476741, 0.173300464636333, 0.142953358039464];    
singularRows = find(sum(xyz,2) == 0);
if (~isempty(singularRows))
    xyz(singularRows,:) = bsxfun(@plus, xyz(singularRows,:), black);
end

uvl = zeros(size(xyz));
uvl(:,1) = clipdivide(4 * xyz(:,1), xyz * [1; 15; 3]);
uvl(:,2) = clipdivide(6 * xyz(:,2), xyz * [1; 15; 3]);
uvl(:,3) = xyz(:,2);

function C = clipdivide(A, B)    
    B(B < eps) = eps;
    C = A ./ B;
end
```